# Селектор jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть код:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="hiddentext">123</div>
    <a class="button">Показать</a>

</div>
```

Как прописать селектор при клике на кнопку так, чтобы он выбрал hiddentext только этого поста?

```
 $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.hiddentext').show(1000);    
    });
```

Так покажет все элементы, в любом посте, надо только в этом.
Затрудняюсь, помогите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.hiddentext').show(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Для вашей структуры подойдёт и такой вариант тоже:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hiddentext').show(1000);
});
```

Comment: Да, это, конечно, красивее, но, все-же, имхо, не совсем предусмотрительно :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я ж просто показал альтернативу с поправкой, что именно при показанной структуре. Да и плюсанул я ваш ответ тоже не просто так ))

Answer (score 2):

**Ликбез:**

Все элементы, которые содержатся внутри одного и того же элемента (имеют общего непосредственного предка), являются сестринскими по отношению друг к другу.

Отбор сестринских элементов осуществляется точно так же, как и отбор следующих элементов, за исключением того, что данный селектор будет отыскивать все сестринские элементы, располагающиеся после начального, а не только следующий, т.е. тот, который располагается непосредственно вслед за начальным.

Для выбора сестринских элементов необходимо указать селектор начального элемента, символ "тильды" (~) и селектор сестринских элементов:

> начальный~сестринский

```
$('.button').click(function() {
       $('~.hiddentext',this).show(1000);
});
```