# Почему не работает конструкция this на JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, почему не работает такая конструкция на JQuery?

```
<li class="nav__first-level-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="nav__first-level">Первый уровень</a>
  <!-- Второй уровень -->
  <ul class="nav__secont-level hide">
    <li> <a href="#">Второй уровень</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Второй уровень</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Второй уровень</a> </li>
  </ul>
</li>

$(".nav__first-level").click(function() {
    $( this ).find(".nav__secont-level").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Пытаюсь сделать при клике на первый уровень меню (убирать класс скрывающий блок) показывать второй уровень. 
Пробовал сделать через **children**, тщетно.

```
$(".nav__first-level").click(function() {
    $( this ).children(".nav__secont-level").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: Выглядит как рабочий код, если `.nav__secont-level` является дочерним для `.nav__first-level`. Приведите код демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, спасибо, моя ошибка. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLaLbY. Класс .nav__first-level не являлся родителем

Comment: `$('.nav__first-level').on('click', function() { $(this).siblings('.nav__secont-level').toggleClass('hide') })`

Comment: [ТУТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146726/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-jquery) приведен ещё один вариант нахождения сестринского элемента.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, я скорее всего просто класс поменяю, на родителя .nav__first-level-wrapper, вроде не самое плохое решение

Comment: тогда придется либо прерывать всплытие события при клике на второй уровень, либо у вас будет второй уровень закрываться при клике на второй уровень .... не самое лучшее решение в плане расширяемости, но если это не требуется, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Селектор jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146726/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как элемент `.nav__secont-level` не является дочерним для `$(this)`, то метод `.children()` не сможет его найти. Необходимо использовать `.next()` или `.siblings()`, которые возвращают следующий и соседние элементы соответственно.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/xmekxzLj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
find(), children()
```

эти ф-ции ищут дочерние элементы, а вы же хотите скрывать/показывать следующий на том же уровне, а не дочерний

```js
$(".nav__first-level").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.nav__secont-level.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav__first-level-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="nav__first-level">Первый уровень</a>
  <!-- Второй уровень -->
  <ul class="nav__secont-level hide">
    <li> <a href="#">Второй уровень</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Второй уровень</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Второй уровень</a> </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```